# Zend - redirect to "public" subdir with htaccess

Tags: php, zend-framework

I started to develop an application with netbeans+zend. I have a host and uploaded the project files there, but I haven't managed to redirect the request from the root directory to the public subdirectory yet. I get the 404 error page of the zend project by every request.
Can anybody help me?

addons:

I redirect with the following htaccess (wwwroot/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

In the public folder is the default (generated) htaccess of the project (wwwroot/public/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The zend project is in the wwwroot, I don't have any access to apache config, can create only htaccess files. The zend framework files are in the wwwroot/library/zend. The project files are included on localhost, but not on my godaddy host. :S

On localhost I get the porject 404 page by every request, on the godaddy I get the following error:

> Warning:
>   require_once(Zend/Application.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/content/14/7811914/html/public/index.php
>   on line 18

If I remove the wwwroot/htaccess, and use "http://localhost/public/" I get the zend fw opening page, so it works, without redirection, so I think on localhost I have a routing problem and I have to overwrite something in bootstrap, or somewhere... On godaddy I don't know what the problem is... Maybe the lowercase file names, I try to extend the autoload module with a tolowercase function call... (tomorrow...)

Comment: There are several things that can be wrong here. for instance your .htaccess could be buggy; your site's support for url rewriting; the document root on your Apache configuration. It wud be helpful if you gave more information or atleast give a sample request URI

Comment: I don't have any problem with htaccess I think.
The problem on localhost is maybe by the routing of project, on godaddy I got some autoload bug, but I don't know why :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://www.warpturn.com/zend-framework-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux/

It was a set_include_path problem. I replaced the set_include_path paramters in public/index.php, and after that everything was ok.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember on that, it was a year ago :S You should try to put the zend directory or the parent of that in the include path according to what I wrote in the solution.

Comment: I think you should add the location of your page to the include path. After that you can refer to the Zend directory as './Zend', or any other classes as they were in the document root. Btw. we got now the next version of zend maybe with other features...

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your webserver using the new document root.

When having access to the .httpd.conf you can set the new document root there for you domain.

When using confixx you find that below the point "domains", in your admin panel.

when using plesk you can edit the vhost specific config in the domain's conf foler named vhost.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/public>
Options -Includes -ExecCGI
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/public
```

After that run your plesk update script.

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -u --vhost=yourdomain.com
```

Comment: By the way this also set's your env to development as well, so modify my script. Maybe setting the DocumentRoot is enough.

Comment: Ohh sry, I was not accurate. :S I have only a godaddy account, so I can't modify the document root...